# Win 10, Miktex, Texniccenter pstricks tikzpicture not rendering properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, miktex2.9

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\listfiles 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2.5,0) arc (180:360:2.5cm and 1.25cm);
    \draw[dashed] (-2.5,0) arc (180:0:2.5cm and 1.25cm);
    \draw (0,2.5) arc (90:270:1.25cm and 2.5cm);
    \draw[dashed] (0,2.5) arc (90:-90:1.25cm and 2.5cm);
    \draw (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \draw (0,0) --(2.5,0);
    \node at (.5,.2) {$3$ in};
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{.5cm}\hspace{2cm}
\psset{yunit=.35cm,xunit=.35cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,-0.8)(20.8,11.8)
 % \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabelcolor=white,linewidth=.7pt,gridcolor=black,griddots=5](-8,-8)(8,8)
 % \psaxes[linewidth=1pt,Dx=8,Dy=8,labels=all,arrowsize=5pt]{<->}(0,0)(-8.7,-8.7)(8.7,8.7)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0,0)(20,0)(15,10)(5,10)(0,0)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](15,10)(15,0)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](5,10)(5,0)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](4.5,0)(4.5,0.5)(5.5,0.5)(5.5,0)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](14.5,0)(14.5,0.5)(15.5,0.5)(15.5,0)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](5,9.5)(5.5,9.5)(5.5,10)
  \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](14.5,10)(14.5,9.5)(15,9.5)
  \rput[lt](9,-.5){$22$ ft}
  \rput[lt](9,11){$22$ ft}
  \rput[bl](-1,3.4){$12$ ft}
  \rput[bl](19,3.4){$12$ ft}
  \rput[bl](2,-1){$7$ ft}
  \rput[bl](17,-1){$7$ ft}
  \rput[bl](5.5,5){$10$ ft}
  \rput[bl](12,5){$10$ ft}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this on my computer either the tikzpicture renders as a solid ball and the pstricks is fine, or the tikzpicture renders find and the pstricks does not.  It use to work before I updated the the packages :(.  My work computer still compiles correctly as I have not updated it.

First picture compiled with: Latex->PS->PDF (what I normally use)

Second picture compiled with: Latex->PDF

[image: tikxpicture not correct - pstricks correct]

[image: tikxpicture correct - pstricks not correct]

Comment: Maybe try to compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: You must add `-dNOSAFER` to the ps2pdf call, the latest ghostscript has disabled opacity for security reasons.

Comment: Both worked! THANKS  How do I make comments as answers?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The -dNOSAFER flag no longer works :(.  I tried it on the arguments line and it created a file called -dNOSPACER.  When I used the executable it get returned a single blank page.  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\ps2pdf.exe  -dNOSAFER

Comment: I can't update currently miktex, but with my version (which is only a few days old) it works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  - that seemed to work when I updated miktex through the concole.